# How do I cross-compile a Qt-project with a recipe in yocto

Tags: qt, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to Cross-compile a qt-project from a recipe. I have created a recipe file but when I try to bitbake it. I am met with error

Here is my recipe file

```
DESCRIPITION = "my_project File Transfer"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "git://git@bitbucket.org/johndoe/my_ui.git;protocol=ssh;rev=master"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git/my_project"

RDEPENDS_${PN} ="bash"
inherit qmake5
require recipes-qt/qt5/qt5.inc

do_install_append() {
    ## Creating Folder Structure
    install -d ${D}/opt/my_project/bin
    install -d ${D}/home/root/my_project
    install -d ${D}/home/root/my_project/font
    install -d ${D}/home/root/my_project/Images
    install -d ${D}/home/root/my_project/Qml
    ###compile the project  
    oe_runmake INSTALL_ROOT=${D} install
    #### Copying files
    install -m 0755 ${S}/font/* ${D}/home/root/my_project/font/
    install -m 0755 ${S}/Images/* ${D}/home/root/my_project/Images/
    install -m 0755 ${S}/Qml/* ${D}/home/root/my_project/Qml/
}


FILES_${PN} = "/home/root/my_project"
```

The error that I see is

```
Sstate summary: Wanted 335 Found 327 Missed 8 Current 1958 (97% match, 99% complete)
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: myproject-project-1.0-r0 do_configure: Error calling /home/blue/yacto/rpi-qt5/build/tmp/work/all-poky-linux/myproject-project/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qmake -makefile -o Makefile        /home/blue/yacto/rpi-qt5/build/tmp/work/all-poky-linux/myproject-project/1.0-r0/git/myproject/myproject.pro  -- 
ERROR: myproject-project-1.0-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/blue/yacto/rpi-qt5/build/tmp/work/all-poky-linux/myproject-project/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.20982)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/blue/yacto/rpi-qt5/build/tmp/work/all-poky-linux/myproject-project/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.20982
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function qmake5_base_preconfigure
| DEBUG: Shell function qmake5_base_preconfigure finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| NOTE: qmake prevar substitution: '   '
| Could not find qmake spec 'linux-oe-g++'.
| Error processing project file: /home/blue/yacto/rpi-qt5/build/tmp/work/all-poky-linux/myproject-project/1.0-r0/git/myproject/myproject.pro
| ERROR: Error calling /home/blue/yacto/rpi-qt5/build/tmp/work/all-poky-linux/myproject-project/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qmake -makefile -o Makefile        /home/blue/yacto/rpi-qt5/build/tmp/work/all-poky-linux/myproject-project/1.0-r0/git/myproject/myproject.pro  --
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/blue/yacto/rpi-qt5/build/tmp/work/all-poky-linux/myproject-project/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.20982)
ERROR: Task (/home/blue/yacto/poky-warrior-21.0.1/meta-rpi_custom/recipes-custom/myproject-project/myproject-project_1.0.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4242 tasks of which 4241 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/blue/yacto/poky-warrior-21.0.1/meta-rpi_custom/recipes-custom/myproject-project/myproject-project_1.0.bb:do_configure
```

I know that in order to cross-compile. I had to run `qmake` from my cross-compile tool-chain location and then run `make` command on it.

I am guessing that is what's missing in my recipe. So my question is, Do I add that in my `do_configure`
if thats the case can anyone help me or point me how do I populate my do_configure
Is it as simple as source /opt/poky/2.7.1/environment---- 
then qmake

I am drawing a blank at this step

Please let me know what am I doing wrong

Edit1: remove `inherit allarch` from recipe

Comment: Your recipe claims to be 'allarch' (so architecture independent), but that seems unlikely to be true if you're also cross-compiling...

Comment: @JussiKukkonen I will remove that and try it out

Comment: @JussiKukkonen Tried it out still gives me the same error

Comment: Which Qt modules are you using and configuring in your project's .pro file? I would just leave `inherit qmake5`  and put `DEPENDS + = "qtbase qtxyz ..."`,  qtxyz would be the list of other dependency modules

Comment: @CleitonBueno I did exactly that. I later figured that out and added `DEPENDS` and It worked. Can you please make your comment as an answer. I see another similar question in Stackoverflow that hasn't had an answer yet.

Comment: @thesillywhat okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just leave `inherit qmake5` and put `DEPENDS + = "qtbase qtxyz ..."`, qtxyz would be the list of other dependency modules.